# Displaying Sub-content Types for RESTful Views in Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

I have two entities (Content types in Drupal 8), foo and bar, for which I've added basic RESTful views, `/foo` and `/bar`. These work fine.

I've also added bar as field in the foo Content type (a foo may have many bars), and when doing a `GET` against the `/foo` RESTful call, I see this:

```
[
    ...
    field_foo_children_bars [ ],
    ...
]
```

...but I do not see any of the fields from any of the bar objects that have been added to the parent foo.

What is the standard and natural Drupal way of displaying the sub-content type's fields in a RESTful call?